# getting error why trying to dffml in development mode?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

These are the commands i am running as mentioned in the documentation

```sh
git clone https://github.com/intel/dffml
cd dffml
python3 -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
python3 -m pip install --prefix=~/.local -e .[dev]
```

But i am getting warnings and error on the last command

**warning**

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -jango (/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
```

**error**

```
    Found existing installation: Pillow 7.0.0
    Uninstalling Pillow-7.0.0:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '_imagingtk.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

And  program stops executing after the error , i dont know what is the source of error and how to remove it, any help is appreciated

Comment: For reference, where in the docs did you find those commands? here? [Getting Set Up To Work On DFFML](https://intel.github.io/dffml/master/contributing/dev_env.html)

Comment: Did you even try googling the warning? I found these questions immediately: [Why do I get this when using pip WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip?](/q/68880743/4518341), [Pip "Ignoring invalid distribution" warning](/q/67613777/4518341), [pip how to remove incorrectly installed package with a leading dash: "-pkgname"](/q/56973015/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error, try using `--user`, like this:

```
python3 -m pip install --user -e .[dev]
```

[Their docs](https://intel.github.io/dffml/master/contributing/dev_env.html) talk about why they don't use `--user`, but the explanation doesn't make much sense to me.

> Installing to your home directory will reduce permissions issues. To do this we use the `--prefix=~/.local` flag. `pip` sometimes gets confused about the `--user` flag (and will blow up in your face if you try to pass it). So we use the `--prefix=~/.local` flag, which has the same effect but should always work.

Specifically, I don't know why `pip` would "get confused", but I'm not an expert.